# HMAC-SHA1 for OAuth Signature in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, oauth

i want to generate oauth 1.0 signature from base string URL but i'm getting invalid signature from algorithm. My output is as follow.

```
code = "woocommerce_rest_authentication_error";
data =     {
    status = 401;
};
message = "Invalid signature - provided signature does not match.";
```

Can anyone help me?? Thanks.

```
 var strURLForSignature : String = String.init(format: "oauth_consumer_key=%@&oauth_nonce=%@&oauth_signature_method=%@&oauth_timestamp=%ld&oauth_version=1.0",API_consumer_key, nonce, "HMAC-SHA1", timestamp)
    print(strURLForSignature)

    strURLForSignature = strURLForSignature.replacingOccurrences(of: "/", with: "%2F")
    strURLForSignature = strURLForSignature.replacingOccurrences(of: ":", with: "%3A")
    strURLForSignature = strURLForSignature.replacingOccurrences(of: "&", with: "%26")
    strURLForSignature = strURLForSignature.replacingOccurrences(of: "=", with: "%3D")

    strURLForSignature = String.init(format: "%@%@", API_MAIN_URL_Oauth,strURLForSignature)

    strURLForSignature = strURLForSignature.replacingOccurrences(of: "/", with: "%2F")
    strURLForSignature = strURLForSignature.replacingOccurrences(of: ":", with: "%3A")
    strURLForSignature = strURLForSignature.replacingOccurrences(of: "=", with: "%3D")

    print(strURLForSignature)

    guard let keyData = key.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8),
        let stringData = strURLForSignature.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8),
        let outputData = NSMutableData(length: Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH)) else {
            return
    }
    outputData.length = Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH)
    let tempData: NSMutableData = NSMutableData(length: 26)!
    keyData.withUnsafeBytes {
        tempData.replaceBytes(in: NSMakeRange(0, keyData.count), withBytes: $0)
    }
    CCHmac(CCHmacAlgorithm(kCCHmacAlgSHA1),
           tempData.bytes, keyData.count,
           tempData.bytes, stringData.count,
           outputData.mutableBytes)
    outhSignature = outputData
        .base64EncodedString(options: [])
    print(outputData
        .base64EncodedString(options: []))
    print(outhSignature)
```

Comment: what is the algorithm?

Comment: i have defined in my code

Comment: can you help me to generate signature for oauth 1.0 ? if you have any other option to generate signature then it will very helpful for me

Comment: ok but can you show me the pattern of signature you want to generate

Comment: i want to generate signature like "zQmam3Ep+kDSanhGW6su7dP4Kuw=" this

Comment: https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift#message-authenticators checkout his library its awesome